# How to store Set<Granted Authority> for JWT Authentication correctly in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, jwt

I am trying to implement Jwt Authentication with user role and permission-based authentification.

While my user gets authenticated, the returned list of authorities during debugging is always empty and not what ist supposed to be, a list of the user's GrantedAuthority. Also during debugging it shows me the following message

```
Expecting an element; looking at ERROR_ELEMENT '(1,53) in /fragment.kt
```

I watched several Java Tutorials and tried to translate them to Kotlin and apart from showing an empty List of Granted Authorities so far it is working.

Here are my code snippets.

**Entity User**

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
data class User(

    ...

    @Transient
    private val grantedAuthorities: Set<GrantedAuthority>,

    ...
) : UserDetails {...}
```

**Role**

```
enum class Role (private val permissions: Set<Permissions>) {
    PRIMARY_OWNER(
        Sets.newHashSet(
            VIEW_FILES,
            ...
            

    private fun getPermissions(): Set<Permissions> {
        return permissions
    }

    fun getGrantedAuthorities(): Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> {
        val permissions = getPermissions().stream()
            .map { permission: Permissions ->
                SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                    permission.getPermission()
                )
            }
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        permissions.add(SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_$name"))
        return permissions
    }
```

**Permissions**

```
enum class Permissions(private val permission: String) {
    // File Management
    VIEW_FILES("files:view"),
    ...


    fun getPermission(): String {
        return permission
    }
}
```

**JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter**

```
class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(private val jwtAuthenticationManager: AuthenticationManager) :
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {

    override fun attemptAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse): Authentication {

        try {
            val authenticationRequest =
                ObjectMapper().readValue(request.inputStream, UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest::class.java)

            val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authenticationRequest.username,
                authenticationRequest.password
            )

            val authenticate = jwtAuthenticationManager.authenticate(authentication)
            return authenticate

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }

    override fun successfulAuthentication(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        chain: FilterChain,
        authResult: Authentication
    ) {

        val key = "blablabla"
        val token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(authResult.name)
            .claim("authorities", authResult.authorities)
            .setIssuedAt(java.util.Date())
            .setExpiration(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusWeeks(2)))
            .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(key.toByteArray()))
            .compact()

        response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
    }
}
```

My best guess is, that I store them wrong, that's why they are not showing but I am not sure and really do not know the best way to fix it.